# Add margin between adjacent elements without adding inner margin to parent container

Tags: html, css

Alright, I can't think of a good way to explain this, so here's a graphic which may help.

I have a 3 column grid of inline-block elements that need to have a margin between themselves. There should not, however, be a margin between the 1st/3rd element of each row and the parent container. Is there a slick way to do this, particularly with CSS? I'm open to any technique that will work.

[image: Marginz]

Html is basically this:

```
<section>
  <article class=“box”>
    <img class="thumb" src="img/image.jpg">
    <p>Name</p>
  </article>
  <article class=“box”>
    <img class="thumb" src="img/image.jpg">
    <p>Name</p>
  </article>
  <article class=“box”>
    <img class="thumb" src="img/image.jpg">
    <p>Name</p>
  </article>
</section>
```

Comment: What does your HTML look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the [`nth-child`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3anth-child) pseudo class to select the third element and remove the margin like:

```
.box {
    margin-right:10px;
}
.box:nth-child(3n) {
    margin-right:0px;
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/3a3La/)**

Comment: Super simple. Thanks!